# Relationship with Hermite polynomials and the Laguerre polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials, recurrence-relations, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

We knew that, the generalized Laguerre polynomials $L_n^{(-1/2)} $ are related to the Hermite polynomials $H_{2n}$ by:

$$ H_{2n}(x) = (-1)^n 2^{2n} n! \, L_n^{(-1/2)} (x^2).$$

I look for a formula connecting the generalized Laguerre polynomials  $L_n^{(-1)} (x)$ and the Hermite polynomials $H_{n}$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: There is only a connection for even and odd Hermite polynomials to the Laguerre polynomials, as seen by the formula presented. One can seek the several forms of Generalized Hermite polynomials for what is being asked. It is also to be understood that the weight functions associated with the generalized Hermite/Laguerre polynomials also change.

Answer (score 1):

Now bear in mind, I've never used Laguerre polynomials before so be warned. Here's my attempt, using some recurrnce relations
described on Wikipedia. Maybe there's simpler, and better, ways of doing it than mine.

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Recurrence_relations

$$
\begin{align}
L_n^{(\alpha+\beta+1)}(x+y)&= \sum_{i=0}^n L_{i}^{(\alpha)}(x)L_{n-i}^{(\beta)}(y)
\\
\Rightarrow L_n^{(1/2)}(x)&= \sum_{i=0}^n L_{i}^{(-1/2)}(x)L_{n-i}^{(0)}(0)
\\
\Rightarrow L_n^{(1)}(x)&= \sum_{i=0}^n L_{i}^{(1/2)}(x/2)L_{n-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)
\\
L_n^{(\alpha)}(x) &= L_n^{(\alpha+1)}(x) - L_{n-1}^{(\alpha+1)}(x) 
\\
\Rightarrow L_n^{(0)}(x)&= L_n^{(1)}(x) - L_{n-1}^{(1)}(x) 
\\
\Rightarrow L_n^{(-1)}(x)&= L_n^{(0)}(x) - L_{n-1}^{(0)}(x)
\\
\Rightarrow L_n^{(-1)}(x) &= \left(L_n^{(1)}(x) - L_{n-1}^{(1)}(x) \right) - \left(L_{n-1}^{(1)}(x) - L_{n-2}^{(1)}(x) \right)
\\
&= L_n^{(1)}(x) - 2L_{n-1}^{(1)}(x)+ L_{n-2}^{(1)}(x)
\\
&=\small{ \left[\sum_{i=0}^n L_{i}^{(1/2)}(x/2)L_{n-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)\right] -2\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} L_{i}^{(1/2)}(x/2)L_{n-1-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)\right]+ \left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} L_{i}^{(1/2)}(x/2)L_{n-2-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)\right]}
\\
&=\small{L_{n}^{(1/2)}(x/2)L_{0}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)+L_{n-1}^{(1/2)}(x/2)L_{1}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)-2L_{n-1}^{(1/2)}(x/2)L_{0}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} L_{i}^{(1/2)}(x/2)\left[L_{n-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)-2L_{n-1-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)+L_{n-2-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)\right]}
\\
&=\small{L_{n}^{(1/2)}(x/2)+L_{n-1}^{(1/2)}(x/2)\left(\frac{1-x}{2}-2\right)+\ldots}
\\
&=\small{\left[\sum_{j=0}^n L_{j}^{(-1/2)}(x)\right]+\left[\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} L_{j}^{(-1/2)}(x)\right]\left(\frac{-3-x}{2}\right)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\left(\left[\sum_{j=0}^n L_{j}^{(-1/2)}(x)\right]\left[L_{n-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)-2L_{n-1-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)+L_{n-2-i}^{(-1/2)}(x/2)\right]\right)}
\end{align}$$

---

So now you can substitute in your relation $H_{2n}(x) = (-1)^n 2^{2n} n! \, L_n^{(-1/2)} (x^2)$, and you're done, albeit with a rather convoluted formula.